# C fwrite() won't save every data in the file

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fwrite

```
int nrAnimals = 0;
ANIMAL animals[10];
addTestData(animals, &nrAnimals);

static void addTestData(ANIMAL* animals, int* nrAnimals)
{
ANIMAL a1 = {"Max", Dog, Male, 12, "Schoolstraat 1", {1, 2, 3}};
ANIMAL a2 = {"Kiekerjan", Cat, Female, 4, "boven in boom", {4, 3, 2}};
ANIMAL a3 = {"Lorre", Parrot, Male, 40, "werk", {8, 9, 10}};
ANIMAL a4 = {"Fifi", Dog, Female, 1, "1Kerkstraat 13", {1, 1, 100}};
ANIMAL a5 = {"Piep", GuineaPig, Male, 3, "1thuis", {3, 4, 1}};
ANIMAL a6 = {"Fifi", Dog, Female, 1, "2Kerkstraat 13", {1, 1, 100}};
ANIMAL a7 = {"Piep", GuineaPig, Male, 3, "2thuis", {3, 4, 1}};
ANIMAL a8 = {"Fifi", Dog, Female, 1, "3Kerkstraat 13", {1, 1, 100}};
ANIMAL a9 = {"Piep", GuineaPig, Male, 3, "3thuis", {3, 4, 1}};

animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a1;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a2;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a3;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a4;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a5;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a6;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a7;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a8;
animals[(*nrAnimals)++] = a9;
}


int writeAnimals(const char* filename, const ANIMAL* animalPtr, int nrAnimals)
 {
     if (filename == NULL || animalPtr == NULL || nrAnimals)
     {

     }
     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen(filename, "w");
     fwrite(animalPtr, sizeof(ANIMAL),nrAnimals,fp);
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
 }
```

above are the struct I want to include in my file. after I run this code and
open the file with hexeditor I only see a lot of zero's.

[File where I save the animals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXu6R.png)

Am I doing something wrong here?

edit:

```
void test_writeAnimals(void)
{
int nrAnimals = 0;
ANIMAL animals[10];
addTestData(animals, &nrAnimals);
int number;
FILE *fp;
number = writeAnimals("Argenis", animals, 10);
fclose(fp);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(1, number);
}
```

this is how I call the function.

```
typedef enum
{
Cat,
Dog,
GuineaPig,
Parrot
} SPECIES;

typedef enum
{
Male,
Female
} SEX;

typedef struct
{
int Day;
int Month;
int Year;
} DATE;

#define MaxNameLength 25
#define MaxLocationLength 100
typedef struct
{
char    Name[MaxNameLength];
SPECIES Species;
SEX     Sex;
int     Age;
char    FoundAtLocation[MaxLocationLength];
DATE    DateFound;
} ANIMAL;
```

Comment: What are `Dog`, `Cat`,... they aren't strings, right? Are they in a enum or something?

Comment: @lpares12 i just included the enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `fwrite` writes the fixed amount of data that you tell it. The unused space in the structures does not magically vanish.

For example, the first member of the `struct` is

```
char Name[MaxNameLength];
```

so `fwrite` will write all 25 characters of `Name` to the file, regardless of the fact that the first animal's name "Max" has only 3 letters.

The second member is `Species` which you initialised as `Dog` so has the value `1`.

The third member is `Sex` which you initialised as `Male` and has the value `0`.

Furthermore, the `struct` itself is padded so that each member is aligned to 32-bits, and the first member `Name` actually takes 28 bytes of the `struct`, not 25.

So the first 28 bytes of the hex dump show "Max" of length 25 plus 3 bytes padding, followed by `01 00 00 00` which is the 32-bit value for `Dog` in little-endian format, followed by `00 00 00 00`, the 32-bit value of `Male`.

```
4D 61 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
```

and so on.

Comment: so all the data is in the file and when would want to read it with fread it should return all the values?

Comment: It should do so, so long as reading back to the identical `struct`. But *if* the `struct` contains pointers then it would be dangerous, because those memory pointers when read back in would be meaningless. In that case another way should be found.